# How can I map array of objects to required format of array of hashes like [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

How can I map array of objects to required format as below

```
courses.map do |c|
  {
    'name' : c.name,
    'topic' : c.topic
  }
end
```

Its results in

```
[{ :name => 'science', :topic => 'chapter 1'}, { :name => 'math', :topic => 'chapter 2'}]
```

But I want this to print like

```
[{ 'name':'science', 'topic':'chapter 1'}, { 'name':'math', 'topic':'chapter 2'}]
```

PS : I have tried :

1. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys
2. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys

Comment: Do you want to generate JSON?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use string as hash keys instead of symbol, you could:

```rb
courses.map do |c|
  {
    'name' => c.name,
    'topic' => c.topic
  }
end
```

results in:
`[{ 'name' => 'science', 'topic' => 'chapter 1'}]`

Comment: I want like [{ 'name':'science', 'topic':'chapter 1'}, { 'name':'math', 'topic':'chapter 2'}]

Comment: => should be replaced by :

Comment: @AkashKinwad That may be impossible, because in Ruby `{ 'a': 1 }` equal to `{ a: 1 }`, which equal to `{ :a => 1 }`. So why would you have to use `{ 'a': 1 }` format?

Comment: I have to call third party API, which has fixed pattern of URL

Comment: If the final result you want is string,  you could check out the other answer from Cary Swoveland

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with old vs new hash syntax. You cannot convert output to the new syntax. It will always use the old syntax. It probably expects a JSON string. You can get it by using `.to_json`

Use `to_json` on your result and pass that to API endpoint.

`[{ :name => 'science', :topic => 'chapter 1'}, { :name => 'math', :topic => 'chapter 2'}].to_json`

`=> "[{\"name\":\"science\",\"topic\":\"chapter 1\"},{\"name\":\"math\",\"topic\":\"chapter 2\"}]"`

Answer (score 0):

First define an array of structs for illustration.

```
S = Struct.new(:name, :topic) { }
arr = [S.new('science', 'chapter 1'), S.new('math', 'chapter 2')]
```

so that, for example,

```
arr[0].name  #=> 'science'
arr[1].topic #=> 'chapter 2'
```

Then

```
'[' +
arr.map { |inst| "{ 'name':'#{inst.name}', 'topic':'#{inst.topic} }" }
   .join(', ') +
']'
  #=> "[{ 'name':'science', 'topic':'chapter 1 }, { 'name':'math', 'topic':'chapter 2 }]"
```